# Drag image here, drop image here, or drag and drop image here?

Tags: image, drag-n-drop, uploading, upload

Are there any objective reasons to choose one of the below options?

I don't know whether to go with drag image here, drop image here, or drag and drop image here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the least amount of wording while still giving clear instructions.

**Drag image here** 
or
**Select Image**

Maximum filesize: 2mb, allowed files: .jpeg, .png, .gif.

Its important to also give the user the option to browse his files instead of using drag & drop.

Also display the maximum file size and if you only allow a limited datatype tell the user too, so he knows before trying to upload a 10mb file and getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

For me "Drag image here" means you dragging an image in the area, can bew misleading, but of course it depends on the audience, and since they know what's drag n drop it wont be problematic. Maybe "Drop image here" would be better, but i think both can work.

Or you can achieve this from another perspective:
"Add Images 
 Drag and drop area ///smaller font and lighter color but still visible/
 Select image"

Google Drive interaction message when trying to do the D&D is (draging any file over the interface): 
"Drop files to upload them". 
In case of empty state their message is: 
"Drop files here 
 or use the "New" button".